# Making an "image" of the whole filesystem in C#

Tags: c#, xml, image, filesystems, administration

In school were making some administration software, and I to make an application to upload files from a other computer in the internet to a FTP-server. 
(We need to implement it with a windows service installed on the pc we want to administrate.)

So I need to make something like a "file explorer", where I can maybe rightclick on a file, and press Upload.
Lets say the admin PC is PC1 and the PC we want to administrate is PC2

I thought about PC1 sending PC2 a message, when he wants a fresh image of the whole filesystem.
When PC2 receives such a message, he uploads the image onto a FTP server.

How could I implement that "image"?
I just need to know folder names, absolute folder path, and file names (maybe file size and other infos too) to rebuild the image in a treeview.

I thought about implementing it with XML.
something like:

```
<fileSystem>
  <drive name="c:">
    <item type="folder" name="folder1">
      <item type="file" name="file1"/>
      <item type="file" name="file2"/>
      <item type="folder" name="folder2"/>
      <item type="folder" name="folder3">
        <item type="file" name="file3"/>
      </item>
    </item>
  </drive>
</fileSystem>
```

Are there any other, maybe better solutions? How would you do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The filesystem metadata looks fine.  The bigger concern here is the communication between the 3 pieces involved.  Presumably, PC1 and PC2 are behind firewalls, and as such can't be contacted directly from each other.  A typical option is to introduce a server that they can both contact and have that server handle the communication between the clients.  That being said, depending on your requirements it might make more sense to have the server hold a copy of the PC2 file listing somewhere local to itself (like a database) and then have the server give that info to PC1.

Comment: There is a server between em. 
So implementing it with XML is OK?
Wont such a XML file be too big?

Comment: "too big" is relative.  Do you plan on storing this info in the server and periodically updating it, or it strictly between PC1 and PC2?  If it's just between the two, then the two main options are to generate the whole thing once, or query each directory as it is browsed.  A hybrid of this might be to query to a certain directory level, so you could for example get 3 directories deep, then you'd have to query if you wanted more.

Comment: Sending the whole thing at once I think would be less of a "how big is the xml file" issue and more of a "why does it take so long to get a listing of the entire filesystem" issue.

Comment: Mh, would this take so long because the XML-Generation takes so long or because of the upload time?

Comment: My guess is that it would take a long time to actually iterate through the files.  Writing that out to XML and transferring the file will probably be relatively quick in comparison

Answer (score 0):

As Justin said, your data model looks good, and communication between the 2 hosts could take some serious thought.

Perhaps you could investigate Signalr.net, which could be used from a Windows application or a web based approach. I haven't used the technology but here is a link to get you started: [Introduction to SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr)
I believe it would be a case of:

1. Install Signalr Server
2. Send messages between the hosts.

eg.

- PC1. Send Message asking for a listing of available drives
- PC2. Responds with C:, D: etc
- PC1  Sends message asking for C: contents
- PC2  Responds with Folder\, Folder2\, File1.txt etc

Using this approach means that you don't have to take an "image" or snapshot of filesystem, making it quicker and require less bandwith.